# YAJL on the iPhone

Tags: iphone, objective-c, cocoa-touch

Has anyone got the YAJL Json parsing framework to work with iPhone? And if you have can you post simple instructions on how to link to it.

I want to use it with the MGTwitterEngine framework.

Currently I am getting these errors..

"yajl_get_error" referenced from

.. and a few tohers very similar.

YAJL
http://lloyd.github.com/yajl/

MGTwitterEngine
http://mattgemmell.com/2008/02/22/mgtwitterengine-twitter-from-cocoa

Thanks,

Dan

Answer (score 3):

The objective-c bindings for yajl should work on the iPhone. http://github.com/gabriel/yajl-objc/tree/master

I built a static library and seems to be working ok.

Answer (score 1):

I don't know if it works with MGTwitterEngine, but; try json-framework for iPhone, which I've used successfully:

http://code.google.com/p/json-framework/

Comment: apparently, YAJL is faster than the json-framework on a phone. http://rel.me/2009/10/08/json-parsing-speed-test-yajl-vs-sbjson-iphone/

Answer (score 1):

I know this question is OOOLD, but I just found [instructions](https://github.com/mattgemmell/MGTwitterEngine/wiki/Building-and-testing-MGTwitterEngine) from the MGTwitterEngine creator himself on how to build and use MGTwitterEngine successfully.

I hope that helps.

Answer (score 0):

[Three20 has YAJL support.](https://github.com/facebook/three20/tree/master/src/extThree20JSON/) It doesn't seem to use yajl-objc.